# Making Gmail to use "Reply all" automatically in mailing list replies

Tags: gmail

I am using Gmail and have subscribed to several mailing lists (Mailman based).

Gmail defaults to "reply to person" instead of "reply to list" when I try to reply the mailing list messages.

Is there any way to change this behavior?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It’s either all or nothing, meaning that you *can* change the default behavior, but it will affect *all* of the emails you receive, not just the ones from your mailing lists.

To change the default behavior, follow the steps below:

1. Go to *Settings* → *General*
2. Search for **Default reply behavior**
   [image]
3. Set it to **Reply all**
4. Click **Save Changes** at the bottom of the page